# Find $f(x)$ for $f'(x) = f(x) \ln(f(x))$ and $f(0) = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$f'(x) = f(x) \ln\big(f(x)\big)$$

$$f(0) = 1, \qquad  f(x) > 0$$

I am studying for finals on my own and this exercise is really bothering me because I can't seem to solve it. If I divide by $f(x)$ I get $\ln'f(x) = \ln f(x)$ but then I don't know what to do. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: please check my edit of your question.

Comment: Sorry but I am on mobile right now and really new to this site. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Set $\ln(f(x))=g(x)$ and see if you can continue.

Comment: are you sure about the initial condition $f(0) = 1?$ it would be nice if you have $f(1) = e.$

Comment: @abel: isn't it nice as well that $f(x)=1$ ?

Comment: Please check the answer from alexk745, it's me.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, i see that now. an $y\ln y$ satisfies the uniqueness criteria. so $y = 1$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $f(x)>0$, let $g(x)=\ln(f(x))$, i.e. $f(x)=e^{g(x)}$.

The equation turns to

$$e^{g(x)}g'(x)=e^{g(x)}g(x),$$
which can be simplified as
$$g'(x)-g(x)=0,$$ with $g(0)=0$.

Multiplying by $e^{-x}$,

$$g'(x)e^{-x}-g(x)e^{-x}=\left(g(x)e^{-x}\right)'=0,$$
and 
$$g(x)e^{-x}=C^{st}=g(0)e^{-0}=0,$$ hence
$$g(x)=0,f(x)=1.$$

Comment: Credit to @user1397009 for a hint on the final part.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=e^{u}$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
dy&=&e^{u}du \\
u&=&\ln y
\end{eqnarray}
From which (with a little rearrangement)
\begin{equation}
\frac{e^{u}du}{u.e^{u}}=dx
\end{equation}
Thus
\begin{equation} \ln u = x+c
\end{equation}
Hence,
\begin{equation}
u=ae^{x}
\end{equation}
Or
\begin{equation}
y=e^{ae^{x}}
\end{equation}

Comment: if $y=e^u$ , $y\neq ln u$ unless $e^u=\ln u$ ?

Comment: @3d0 typo rectified.

Answer (score 2):

writing your equations as $$\frac{dy}{dx} = y \ln y $$ you can see that it is separable. so $$\frac{dy}{y\ln y} = dx \to x =  \int_1^y \frac{dy}{y \ln y} = \int_1^y \frac{d \,( \ln y)}{\ln y} = \ln (\ln y)\big|_1^y = diverges$$

there is trouble with the initial value $f = 1$ at $x = 0.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\ln{f(x)}$$
$$ \frac{d\ln{f(x)}}{dx}=\ln{f(x)}$$

Call $g(x)=\ln(f(x))$

$$g'(x)=g(x)$$
$$g(x)=ce^{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

I am the original poster but because I am curious about this and wanted to format my text properly, I logged in from my computer. (What is the formatting for the <=> symbol btw?)

So what I finally did was:

Let $g(x) = lnf(x)$ (1)

$g'(x) = g(x)$

$e^xg(x) - e^xg'(x) = 0$

$e^xg(x) + e^x(-g'(x)) = 0$

$(e^xg(x))' = 0$

$e^xg(x) = c$

From (1)=> $g(0) = lnf(0) = 0$

So $c = e^0g(0) = 1 * 0 = 0$

<=> $e^xg(x) = 0$

$e^xlnf(x) = 0$

$lnf(x) = 0$

$f(x) = 1$ for every $xεR$

Your answers really helped me and led me to the answer. Is it correct though?

Comment: Yes it is, but with a little sign error.

Comment: Uhmm is $e^xg(x) = -c$ what you mean?

Comment: nope, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cheating to death, we notice that as $f(x)$ and $e^{x}$ are nonzero and

$$\frac{{f'(x)}-f(x)\ln(f(x))}{f(x)e^{x}}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}e^{-x}-\ln(f(x))e^{-x}=\left(\ln(f(x))e^{-x}\right)'=0.$$

Then,

$$\ln(f(x))e^{-x}=C^{st}=\ln(f(0))e^{-0}=0,$$

and $$f(x)=1.$$